# Embedded image visible in mailboxes other than Microsoft Outlook

Tags: java, html, outlook, jakarta-mail, multipart

I created an email sending job which pics the receivers email id from the excel sheet and an email content from the html file(with embedded image) both placed in a system locally.
But when the mail is sent through the job the image is not visible in MS Outlook but visible in yahoo and gmail as an attachment.

email sending code:

```
while (it.hasNext())
        {
            ReadHTMLContent content = new ReadHTMLContent();
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart();

            to = (String) it.next();
            b = to.matches(emailCheck);

            if (b!= null && b == true) {
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

                msgContent = fetchMailContent();

                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(to));
                message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

                messageBodyPart1.setContent(msgContent, "text/html");

                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);

                String collect = content.getImageSrc();

                String imgStrng = collect;

                DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(imgStrng);

                messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));

                messageBodyPart2.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");

                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

                message.setContent(multipart);

                Transport.send(message);

                System.out.println("Sent message successfully to " + to);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Email ID " + to);
            }
        }
```

Sample HTML from where i am getting the mail content has an embedded image, stored locally in a system:

```html
<html>
  <head><title>Sample test mail job</title></head>
  <body bgcolor=white>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h1>Testing EMail crone job</h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <p>Weather is cold today </p>
 <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="D:\\Email POC\\images\\Koala.jpg">
        </td>
      </tr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know how is it possible to make it visible in outlook mail box as well.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

> img src=" "

You need to add a reference to an image loaded to any web server or add an image as a hidden attachment. So, the result markup should look like the following one:

> img src="cid:attachmentName"

1. Add the attachment using the Attachments.Add method.
2. Set the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property using the PropertyAccessor object.
3. Set the cid value (see #2) for the reference in the message body.

```
      string img = "<br/><p><o:p><img src=\"" + att.FileName
         + "\" width=1 height=1 border=0 /></o:p></p>";
      item.HTMLBody = item.HTMLBody.Replace("</body>", img + "</body>");
      string PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E";
      string HIDDEN_ATTACHMENT = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B";
      var pa = att.PropertyAccessor;
      if (pa != null)
      {
         pa.SetProperty(PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, att.FileName);
         pa.SetProperty(HIDDEN_ATTACHMENT, false);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The msgContent string needs to reference the attached image using the Content-Id you've specified, i.e., using:

```
<img src="cid:image"/>
```

If msgContent is being created by some other program, you may need to process the html and change the references to the image.